# tidying multiple columns with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I know data.table is able to tidy multiple columns at once, unlike dplyr, which relies on multiple `gather` and `spread` steps that can be difficult to visualize.

Here's a knotty problem for the tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data_frame(month_1 = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Jun"),
                        score_1 = c(4, 5, 6, 4),
                        month_2 = c("Jan", "Mar", NA, NA),
                        score_2 = c(3, 2, NA, NA),
                        month_3 = c("Feb", "Mar", "Jun", NA),
                        score_3 = c(8, 7, 4, NA))

# A tibble: 4 x 6
  month_1 score_1 month_2 score_2 month_3 score_3
  <chr>     <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
1 Jan           4 Jan           3 Feb           8
2 Feb           5 Mar           2 Mar           7
3 Mar           6 NA           NA Jun           4
4 Jun           4 NA           NA NA           NA
```

My desired result would be:

```
id month score
1  Jan   4
1  Feb   5
1  Mar   6
1  Jun   4
2  Jan   3
2  Mar   2
3  Feb   8  
3  Mar   7
3  Jun   4
```

data.table users can solve this by melting with patterns, as:

```
melt(setDT(df), measure = patterns("^month", "^score"))
```

But since there's no equivalent dplyr function, I understand there will need to be several `spread`. It seems like my solution below should work, but the second `spread` goes awry:

```
df %>% 
  gather(key, value) %>% 
  mutate(id = parse_number(key),
         key = str_replace(key, "_[0-9]", "")) %>% 
  spread(key, value )
```

Before marking this as a duplicate, please give it a try. Similar questions have the unique id in an existing column. This example has ids in the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can process `month` and `score` columns separately and then join them with `purrr::map_dfc`:

```
map_dfc(c("month", "score"), 
        ~ df %>%
          select_at(vars(matches(.x))) %>%
          gather(key, !!.x) %>%
          separate(key, c("col", "id"), sep="_")) %>% 
  filter(complete.cases(.)) %>%
  select(id, month, score)

# A tibble: 9 x 3
 id   month score 
<chr> <chr> <chr>
1 1     Jan   4    
2 1     Feb   5    
3 1     Mar   6    
4 1     Jun   4    
5 2     Jan   3    
6 2     Mar   2    
7 3     Feb   8    
8 3     Mar   7    
9 3     Jun   4
```

Explanation:

- `map_dfc` iterates over the string values "month" and "score", referring to the current value as `.x`.  The `dfc` suffix performs a `cbind` on the iterated outputs.
- `select_at` chooses only the columns that start with `.x`
- `gather` swings from wide to long, and names the `values` column with the `.x` string value.
- `separate` splits `key` into two columns, containing the column type (which corresponds to the `.x` value) and the `id` number.
- Once the mapping and column-binding is complete, we `filter` out missing values and `select` our target columns.